# Displaying image using CDialog::CreateIndirect

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, localization

I'm modifying MFC C++ code that previews dialogs from Win32 apps when they are being localised/internationalised. One of the limitations of our current approach is that we can't display images from an app being localised, we just insert a placeholder image.

What I would like is a way to enhance this functionality to display an image loaded externally from another app into a child dialog that I create myself.

We preview a dialog from a given Win32 program and recreate the dialogs plus any changes translators have made, using the CDialog::CreateIndirect function.
In effect, we are recreating the original dialog from the Win32 app as a child window of our software.

CDialog::CreateIndirect takes a DLGTEMPLATE structure as an argument which contains all of the data needed to reconstruct a dialog. It's here that we insert the resource id of our placeholder image.

I have searched to see is there are way to write the raw binary data of the image I want to display, or else dynamically add the image into my own app's list of resource IDs so I can use it that way, but ours seems to be an obscure use case.
Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How does the image get loaded when the dialog is displayed in the final application? Why can't you do the same?

Comment: Most likely the dialogs and their child controls are created using the Visual Studio resource editor and which outputs them to .rc files, and then compiled and linked into the executable. The app code just instantiates the dialog and voila, the images appear.  

We can't do that as we need some kind of handle to the image, like a resource id, but the only ones we can use are the ones belonging to the resources of our app (as far as I know)

Comment: How you recreate the dialog? When you recreate the dialog, you make changes to the template. So why not mapping the Id of the picture to a different one? We are using satellite DLLs, so also bitmaps and pictures get translated...

Comment: That's the part I'm trying to figure out - how to map the resources in the third-party executable/module into something that can be displayed using  CDialog::CreateIndirect. I couldn't find a way in the docs to marshal such an image into a dialog template. Any suggestions would be very welcome.